# Cannot get response in JS from Golang server

Tags: javascript, json, go, get

I have HTML:

```
<button onclick="clickListener()" id="form-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
   <script>
        const clickListener = () => {
            console.log('clickListener()')

            fetch("/address")
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })
        }
   </script>
```

Go:

```
func Handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response := jsonResponse{IsAvailable: true, Message: "Available"}

    responseInJsonFormat, err := json.MarshalIndent(response, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cannot convert response data to JSON")
        return
    }

    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    _, err = writer.Write(responseInJsonFormat)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cannot convert response data to JSON")
    }
}
```

If I use browser, I get response in JSON format with data {IsAvailable: true, Message: "Available"}.
Everything works well.

But for some reason I cannot get this data in JS.
All I get as a response in JS is:

[image]

There are no headers or data.
How can I get it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch returns a `Response` object, which then has to be parsed into a usable format, for example JSON or text. Since you want to have a JSON format, you would need to do this:

```
fetch('/address')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Take a look at ["Using the Fetch API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more details.